# Load Background image in css by JSF

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

This is my css file `registrationStyle.css`:

```
body{
    background-image: url("#{resources['images/blue.jpg']}");
}
```

My JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>User Registration</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="registrationStyle.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    This is registration page
</h:body>
</html>
```

The project structure:

[image]

But it can't display image!

**UPDATE**

I want to using `<h:graphicImage` tage:

```
<h:graphicImage name="images/t1.jpg" library="default"/>
```

And i tried this:

```
<h:graphicImage name="t1.jpg" library="images"/>
```

But it says `Unable to find resource default, images/t1.jpg` ?

[image]

Comment: You need `background-image: url("#{resource['images/blue.jpg']}");` instead. Pay close attention at `#{resource[...]}`. It is not `#{resources[...]}`.

Comment: @Tiny most of the time you give just comments even if you provide great and helpful answers, I am really wondering why :)

Comment: Uh! The folder name is not `resource`. It is `resources` as it was before. The resource identifier here `#{resource[...]}` is however, `resource`.

Comment: @Tarik : The prime reason is English. I lack English severely as I am not educated. It is really hard to learn a foreign language just by reading and/or writing.

Comment: @Tiny your english is better than mine, I am sure you can make better answers than many people can do, I already saw your profile and I admire your patience and hardworking, hope you will continue on that way and don't give up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h:outputStylesheet` is for loading CSS files, to include an image file inside your JSF page you should use the `h:graphicImage` Tag like this:

`<h:graphicImage name="blue.jpg" library="images"/>`

**Update:**

In order to load a background Image, the best solution is to follow Tiny's suggestion (within comments) and use:

```
body{
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/blue.jpg']}");
}
```

**See also:**

- [Tag graphicImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/graphicImage.html)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: @SajjadHTLO you really need to read the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used you will anderstand how to use the JSF resource, just read BalusC's answer